# Recreating html table type cell and column width layout with css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to display data in a table, but  tag is not allowing me to do the things I want to. The next best thing is using grid, however I am unable to style columns in a way that suits me.
My goal is to make column width be the same width of the widest cell of that column. All columns would be dynamic width.

At the moment my css looks like this:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 1fr);
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
```

And all the columns are the same width and not at all dynamic. If I change 1fr > auto; then each row cells have different widths.
In short, I want each rows columns to be the same width as the widest cell of that column from all rows.
Can I achieve this with just html and css or do i need to use js? Should I try doing this with flexbox instead? The  is out of question due to it not fitting the needs of the app.

Edit to clarify expectations and result:
If I set it as repeat(13, 1fr);, then all columns in all rows will be same width. This is not the desired outcome, because I want some columns to be wider or thinner depending on the content inside.
If I set repeat(13, auto);, then columsn have dynamic width, however that happens to all rows, meaning in result I get different col width in each row (one col width might be larger than same col in a different row).
What I want to ultimately achieve, is make a table like structure, where col width on all rows is the width of the widest cell in that column of all the rows. If you take a look at how table tag does it.

Reason why I am not just using table: I need other elements inside the table, that are not allowed inside table tag.

Comment: can you please share an example of your html. I ask because the behaviour you described isn't matching what I expect. Even when you using a container styled like that with `1fr` column width, the actual size will adapt to the cell content... and the elements on the same column will share the same width. At the same time is not clear also why the `<table>` isn't achieving the style you are expecting.. maybe there's something further that you need to do that cannot be achieved but the same column width is there of course

Comment: as an after thought.. if you intended those cells to have the width strictly fitting the content and at max being as wide as the widest cell of the same column, you could just style the grid container with `width: fit-content` and the grid layout with `auto` instead of `1fr`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: in your edit you say _meaning in result I get different col width in each row (one col width might be larger than same col in a different row)_ .. no it's not true. Did you see the answers given? and by the way you were asked to share more details (html) and you didn't

Answer (score 1):

I'm not perfectly sure I got what you meant, but if you intended to have a grid layout table-like where each cell extends its width as max as the widest cell on the same column, but yet not being any wider, a solution could be having the width of the container as `width: fit-content;`and the the grid layout as `grid-template-columns: repeat(13, auto);`

```css
table td{
  border: solid 1px;
}

.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, auto);
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
  gap: 1px;
}

.grid .cell{
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<h1>TABLE layout</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>very large content</td>
    <td>3</td>    
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>    
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>    
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>    
    <td>13</td>    
  <tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>    
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>    
    <td>very large content</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>    
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>    
    <td>13</td>    
  <tr> 
</table>

<h1>GRID layout</h1>

<div class="grid">    
  <!-- row[1] -->
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>    
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>    
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
  <div class="cell">9</div>    
  <div class="cell">10</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
  <div class="cell">12</div>    
  <div class="cell">13</div>    
  
  <!-- row[2] -->
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">very large content</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>    
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>    
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
  <div class="cell">9</div>    
  <div class="cell">10</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
  <div class="cell">12</div>    
  <div class="cell">13</div>    
  
  <!-- row[2] -->
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">d</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>    
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>    
  <div class="cell">very large content</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
  <div class="cell">9</div>    
  <div class="cell">10</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
  <div class="cell">12</div>    
  <div class="cell">13</div>    
  
   <!-- row[2] -->
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">d</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>    
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>    
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
  <div class="cell">9</div>    
  <div class="cell">10</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
  <div class="cell">12</div>    
  <div class="cell">13</div>    
  
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>    
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>    
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
  <div class="cell">9</div>    
  <div class="cell">10</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
  <div class="cell">12</div>    
  <div class="cell">13</div>    
  
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>    
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>    
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
  <div class="cell">9</div>    
  <div class="cell">10</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
  <div class="cell">12</div>    
  <div class="cell">13</div>    
  
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>    
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>    
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
  <div class="cell">9</div>    
  <div class="cell">10</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
  <div class="cell">12</div>    
  <div class="cell">very large content</div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, do this with grid and for that your javascript needs to access relevant element(s) of the document appropriately.  The code may be as under:

```js
// dummy data 
data = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen']

// dummy data
data2 = []

for (let x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
  data2.push(data)
}

theTable = document.getElementById('tbl')

for (row of data2) {

  for (col of row) {

    aCol = document.createElement('div')
    aCol.append(col)

    theTable.append(aCol)
  }

}
```

```css
.theGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="theGrid" id="tbl"></div>
```

Comment: `const data = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen'];
document.getElementById('tbl').innerHTML= Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => data.map(col => \`<div>${col}</div>\`).join('')).join('');`